# Android 4.4 browsers reporting unexpected identifier in array push method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, array-push

Android 4.4.2 Mobile browser is reporting "Unexpected identifier" in the line pointing to "caption: title" in the below function.

```
function createGallery(images, title, container) 
{
    "use strict";

    var obj = [];
    images.map(function(link, idx) { 
      obj.push({
        link,
        caption: title
      });
    });

}
```

I tested the code with browsers in android 6 and it didn't report any syntax error and just works fine. 
It started spitting the error even when I'm not calling the function anywhere.

NOTE: The "use strict" was necessary to fix an earlier error on strict mode issues. UC Browser, Opera Mini and the android built-in browser all reported the same syntax error for Android 4.4.2.

Comment: obj.push({link: link, caption: title}). the reason is the above line

Comment: @AraratHarutyunyan Thanks, that is exactly the problem, but am quite surprised I couldn't see that. But why will old compilers detect syntax errors that new ones ignore?

Comment: please see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old browsers doesn't support the object declaration that you have used. You'd better use the following syntax:

```
{
    link: link,
    caption: title
}
```

this is equivalent to

```
{
    link,
    caption: title
}
```

which is ECMAScript 6 feature